# C++11 pass a member function to a thread using a proxy

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, templates

I try to generate a general way to create threads that have an argunment a class method. But I am not able to compile succesfully the code
I use the the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

class hello{
public:
    void f(){
        cout<<"f"<<endl;
    }
    virtual void ff(){
        cout<<"ff"<<endl;
    }
};

template <typename T, T> struct proxy;

template <typename T, typename R, typename ...Args, R (T::*mf)(Args...)>
struct proxy<R (T::*)(Args...), mf>
{
    static R call(T & obj, Args &&... args)
    {  
    //    function func = T::*mf;
        thread t(&T::*mf, &obj);
        return (obj.*mf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
int main(){
    hello obj;
   typedef proxy<void(hello::*)(), &hello::f> hello_proxy;
   hello_proxy::call(obj);
}
```

When compile the following error is generated

> ```
> In static member function 'static R proxy<R (T::*)(Args ...), mf>::call(T&, Args&& ...)':
> 24:22: error: expected unqualified-id before '*' token
> ```

Comment: `thread t(mf, &obj);` That would get it to compile. But it won't run because a) you should also pass the rest of the arguments to the thread, and b) you allow the `thread ` object to get destroyed without joining or detaching it first - this exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What you mean the rest arguments to the thread, The f is a void function.  About detach and join you are right. Of course it is need.

Comment: Well, your code envisions passing an arbitrary number of `Args...`, which you don't currently forward along to the thread. It would indeed work for the specific example you show, where `sizeof...(Args)` happens to be zero.

Comment: Yes you are right..It is clear to me now how it works. Thank you for the prompt reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    thread t(&T::*mf, &obj);
```

`&T::*mf` is wrong syntax.  Just use `mf`.

```
    thread t(mf, &obj);
```